# React Router server side rendering Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-router

I have been struggling to find a good way of accomplishing this, but essentially what I want to do is render a page via the server, but have subsequent routing be client side via `react-router`. I am able to have a server side router by using `createMemoryHistory` for my router.

```
class Router extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router history={createMemoryHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Index} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Then via the react-rails gem I am able to render the content on the server.

```
<%= react_component('Router', {}, {prerender: true}) %>
```

The issue with this is that the URL's don't change when I navigate to different pages. So ideally I'd want to be able to load the router on the server using `createMemoryHistory`, then once it is loaded I'd want to switch to `browserHistory`.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to accomplish this by setting your `history` prop earlier based on the environment. I am not familiar with the `react_component` on Rails but I am guessing that `MountUp` is your root component.

```
const history = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'server' ? createMemoryHistory : browserHistory;

// ...

class MountUp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}/>
    );
  }
}

// ...

class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router history={this.props.history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Index} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```